# How to run OpenCL programs on Linux (ubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: c, linux, opencl, opencl-c

I am trying to learn OpenCL on my own and I have just started off. Now I am reading this book OpenCL In Action.
I have copied a test code in my file but I am not able to get a hang of how to run that code. That is, how do I compile it ? 
In C, we use gcc to get out file which we can run.
But here in OpenCL with C, I am stuck.

Couldn't find any place with clear info and logic behind how to actually compile.

here's the code that I wanna run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <CL/cl.h>

int main() {
cl_platform_id *platforms;
cl_uint num_platforms;
cl_int i, err, platform_index = -1;
char* ext_data;
size_t ext_size;
const char icd_ext[] = "cl_khr_icd";

err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, NULL, &num_platforms);
if(err < 0) {
perror("Couldn't find any platforms.");
exit(1);
}

platforms = (cl_platform_id*)
malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id) * num_platforms);
clGetPlatformIDs(num_platforms, platforms, NULL);
for(i=0; i<num_platforms; i++) {
err = clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i],
CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS, 0, NULL, &ext_size);
if(err < 0) {
perror("Couldn't read extension data.");
exit(1);
}

ext_data = (char*)malloc(ext_size);
      clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i],CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS,ext_size,ext_data,NULL);
printf("Platform %d supports extensions: %s\n",i, ext_data);


if(strstr(ext_data, icd_ext) != NULL) {
free(ext_data);
platform_index = i;
break;
}
free(ext_data);
}

if(platform_index > -1)
printf("Platform %d supports the %s extension.\n",platform_index,icd_ext);
else
printf("No platforms support the %s extension.\n", icd_ext);
free(platforms);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried doing? Also OpenCL kernels are usually compiled at runtime anyway. The only difference is that you need to link the C code against the OpenCL library.

Comment: I just changed the code. Can you take a look again please

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is with that code - You say you don't know how to compile it, so what am I supposed to see in that code?

Comment: Sorry for misleading, my sdk is located in `/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0` , which library do I link?

Comment: Check the user guide for AMDAPPSDK - section 3.1.2 *Compiling on Linux*: http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_User_Guide2.pdf - it has the instructions for including headers and linking against the library

Comment: This helped a lot ! Found the answer. Will post it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by UnholySheep above in comments we need to link the C code against the OpenCL Library.

Assuming the C source file is named test.c , command to compile it on a 64-bit system would be;

`gcc test.c -lOpenCL -L$AMDAPPSDKROOT/lib/x86_64`

More can be found from the manual provided by AMD:
[AMD_OpenCL_Programming_User_Guide](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_User_Guide2.pdf)

Part specific to this questions is answered in Section 3.1.2 of the user guide as follows,

### Compiling on Linux

> To compile OpenCL applications on Linux, gcc or the Intel C compiler
> must be installed. There are two major steps: compiling and linking.
>
> 1. Compile all the C++ files (Template.cpp), and get the object files. For 32-bit object files on a 32-bit system, or 64-bit object files on
>    64-bit system:
>     g++ -o Template.o -c Template.cpp
>    -I$AMDAPPSDKROOT/include
>     For building 32-bit object files on a 64-bit system:
>     g++ -o Template.o -c Template.cpp
>    -I$AMDAPPSDKROOT/include
> 2. Link all the object files generated in the previous step to the OpenCL library and create an executable.
>     For linking to a 64-bit
>    library:
>     g++ -o Template Template.o -lOpenCL
>    -L$AMDAPPSDKROOT/lib/x86_64
>     For linking to a 32-bit library:
>     g++ -o Template Template.o -lOpenCL -L$AMDAPPSDKROOT/lib/x86

Answer (score 0):

I have an Intel Kaby Lake GT2 GPU on my Dell Inspiron, which runs Ubuntu 18.04. Once OpenCL is installed, the next step in development is getting a simple code sample up and running.

I first put the code outlined [here](https://us.fixstars.com/products/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/first-opencl-program/) into a local directory, and then proceeded to compile using g++

```
g++ *.cpp -lOpenCL
```

Your mileage will vary, you may also need to include header files